# How do I pass a shuffled arraylist of classes from activity to activity without the list being recreated every time?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I've been trying many different methods to pass an arraylist of activity classes in android for an app game . The arraylist starts in MainActivity then through an onClick Listener an element of the arraylist gets called after it has been shuffled. The problem is when this arraylist is called again in a later activity the arraylist has been shuffled again. I don't want the list to be shuffled again unless the user returns to MainActivity. I'm using Collections shuffle to randomize the arraylist. I only want shuffled to be called once through the MainActivity onCreate, then I want to keep that same list. Only if the user returns to MainActivity do I want shuffle to be called again.

```
 public MainActivity extends Activity {

   List<Class<?>> listActivities = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

   onCreate {
     arrayList();
   }     

  public void arraryList() {

     listActivities.add(Activity1.class);
     listActivities.add(Activity2.class);       
     listActivities.add(Activity3.class);

     Collections.shuffle(listActivites)

  }

  //OnClicklistener Button
  OnClick (View v){

      // just an example
      if (v) {

        Intent intent = new (this, listActivities.get(0))
        startActivity(intent);
  }

}
```

Lets say the Intent called Activity2 as `listActivities.get(0)`

```
Activity2 extends MainActivity
```

Then another activity gets called, lets say ActivityNext

In `ActivityNext extends Activity2`

```
Intent intent = new (this, listActivities.get(1))
 startActivity(intent);
```

Gets called.
The problem is since the listActivities is being shuffled many times through the life cycle

```
listActivities.get(1)
```

Could end up being Activity2 again and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: I would suggest you to not use activities, use fragments instead and keep the shuffled List of fragments in your mainActivity and access it by `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getShuffledList()`

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of fragments as A.S. suggests, but it sounds for sure like your list is getting shuffled somewhere that's not expected. Are you extending MainActivity in your other activities? Try running in debug to see exactly when the shuffle call is getting invoked. Also, posting some code from your other activities might shed some light on the situation.

Comment: @Jason yes I am extending MainActivity in the other activities, example (Activity1 extends MainActivity), is that why it's being re-shuffled?

Comment: @A.S. I'm not familiar with using fragments, could you provide an example?

Comment: @creativecoding Yes this could be the cause if the parent onCreate is getting called in your child classes.

Comment: @Jason I don't know if that was part of the cause or not, but I fixed it and what I did was not extend the Activity1 by MainActivity and also I declared listActivities = new ArrayList<Class<?>>() inside the arrayList method which really did the trick. I also put a log in the shuffle method and it only gets called when the app returns to MainActivity. Thanks for the help Jason!